# IndexError : Tuple out of range when passing variable into a python function for a SQL function

Tags: python-3.x, variables, amazon-redshift

I have a SQL that has 2 sub-queries as shown below. When I run it in an SQL editor this runs fine however if I use it as a Python function I get an error

```
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Could anyone advice as to where am I going wrong with this.

```
dwh_cursor.execute(sql.SQL("""
with base as 
(select a.id,a.store, b.prod_id 
from sales a join product b on a.prod_id = b.id), 
sub_query as
(select a.cust_name,b.id, b.prod_id 
from customers a join product b on a.prod_id = b.id)     
select base.store,base.prod_id,sub_query.cust_name 
from base join sub_query on base.id = sub_query.id 
and sub_query.cust_name = {}""").format(sql.Literal(name)))
```

I am using Redshift DB. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are creating two tables before querying from them together in the last query.

However, in your second query you are joining table b on table a without using "on". Instead you are using "where". Try querying the second table with a join like this:

```
from customers a join product b on a.prod_id = b.id
```

instead of:

```
from customers a join product b where a.prod_id = b.id
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I had mis-spelled when I pasted the code here. I have updated the code. I use 'on' instead of 'where' in the second sub-query